# Django admin query/search form

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to add easy querying functionality to multiple Django change list forms.  I'm hoping to provide functionality similar to phpMyAdmin's "Search" tab for tables (as shown on in the images [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/searching-data-using-phpmyadmin-and-mysql) and [here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_database_management.htm)).

This functionality is (nearly) already available in via URL query parameters on an admin change list.  Example query via GET parameters:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/myapp/mymodel/?my_field=something&my_date__gt=2000-01-01
```

Another way to look at this problem is that I need Django filters for arbitrary fields and inputs (without displaying the thousands/millions of possible values for each field).

Is there an existing Django application that provides this functionality already?